# Changing xpath selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

So I'm running into the issue where I need 90% of the time

```
//*[@id='MainContent']/tbody/tr[18]/td[2]
```

while I need 10% of the time

```
//*[@id='MainContent']/tbody/tr[20]/td[2]
```

I'm wondering what the best approach to compensate for this change would be.

Here are pictures of the table, and the html code to the table.
[image]

[image]

I need to capture the `3 Bedrooms` part, and there are times where the `tr` elements swap. Most of the time the first xpath code works, but I need a more efficient way of determining which xpath to use depending on the case at hand.

I know that a starts-with method exists for selenium, but would that allow me to search the actual TD text?

Comment: Can you inspect the text of the first xpath element, and use that to decide which element you need?  i.e. something like `if 'Bedrooms' in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id='MainContent']/tbody/tr[18]/td[2]')` ?

Comment: I could do that, but I'm wondering if there is a method that already exists for selenium that would do just that, so instead of using an if statement, is there a method that searches for the text, and if the text is found can copy the xpath @JohnGordon

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  `if 'something' in element.text:` is about as direct as you can get.

Comment: @JohnGordon Does selenium not have a method that does this lookup directly? For instance, something like this: //*[text()[contains(.,'theText')]]

Comment: Oh, you mean an XPath selector.  It's nothing specifically to do with Selenium.

Comment: @JohnGordon right, sorry I meant within xpath. Most of the time the xpath could be one of the 2 I listed above, but there may be another time that I have not accounted for yet. So I'd like to determine the xpath based on the text of the cell

Comment: If you are using the contents of one cell to decide what other cell you really want, then I'm not sure you can do it within XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To capture the text **3 Bedrooms** with respect to the text **Ttl Bedrms** you can use the following solution:

- `XPath`:

  ```
  //tr[@class='RowStyle']//td[contains(.,'Ttl Bedrms')]//following::td[1]
  ```

Comment: Decided to use the text()= method because I am trying to match case exact text. In the event that they ever update the site, I can rely on the exact text matching and not just contains because there could be multiple places where that text may exist

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `Ttl Bedrms:` text

```
//*[@id='MainContent']//td[contains(., `Ttl Bedrms:`)]/following-sibling::td
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used something similar to this, but I used the text()= method instead of contains(x,x)